# Vue.Draggable integration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.draggable

I'm doing maintenance on a web app that uses Vue, and I'm trying to integrate [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) to provide some drag-and-drop functionality.

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <draggable :list="list">
      <li v-for="element in list">
        {{element.id}}
      </li>
    </draggable>
  </ul>

</template>

<script>
  import draggable from 'vuedraggable'

  export default {
    components: {
      draggable,
    },

    data() {
      return {
        list: [
                {"id":"a517e0ee-9a53-457b-b619-383ab005c970"}
              ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I'm not getting any output on the page, and I'm getting multiple errors in the console with this approach.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function:   (found in <Draggable>)
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at keys (<anonymous>)
    at getComponentAttributes (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:5689), <anonymous>:2829:29)
    at Proxy.render (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:5689), <anonymous>:2921:22)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:723), <anonymous>:3518:22)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:723), <anonymous>:2095:22)
    at Watcher.get (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:723), <anonymous>:2414:25)
    at new Watcher (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:723), <anonymous>:2397:12)
    at mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:723), <anonymous>:2109:17)
    at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:723), <anonymous>:7156:10)
    at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:723), <anonymous>:9157:16)
```

I've tried this with and without a lot of options specified on the Vue.Draggable page, including a `:keys` attribute.

The front end is not my comfort zone, and Vue is pretty unfamiliar to me, so it's entirely possible I've missed something really easy here. I've just been whittling this problem down to a simpler and simpler set of code, and I'm out of ideas.

It's worth mentioning that this page works great with general Vue functionality, including `v-model` binding and `v-if` conditions in multiple places. This example list displays fine until I introduce the `draggable` component. The console output is not helpful enough for me to understand what's wrong.

Does anyone have some insight or guidance on what's going on here?

Comment: I recommend copying the basic example code and modify the data. 
`https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/simple.vue` 
More examples with code `https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/simple`

Comment: This example is based on exactly that with as much extraneous code as possible removed to make the question as simple as possible.

Comment: Did you find solution to this @RonU ?